# How to create a bidirectional many2many relationship in gorm

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

According to [the doc](https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Self-Referential-Many2Many) self-relational `many2many` is like below

```golang
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Friends []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_friends"`
}
```

But I want to be able to model something like this:

```golang
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Followings []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation"`
  Followers []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation"`
}
```

So the following process works well. If `userA` followed `userB`, then `userB` could see `userA` in its followers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve it with these tags:

```golang
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Followings []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;foreignKey:ID;joinForeignKey:UserA;References:ID;joinReferences:UserB"`
  Followers []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;foreignKey:ID;joinForeignKey:UserB;References:ID;joinReferences:UserA"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Followings []*User `gorm:"many2many:followings"`
  Followers []*User `gorm:"many2many:followers"`
}
```

It will result in three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` integer,`created_at` datetime,`updated_at` datetime,`deleted_at` datetime,PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
CREATE TABLE `followings` (`user_id` integer,`following_id` integer,PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`following_id`),CONSTRAINT `fk_followings_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`),CONSTRAINT `fk_followings_followings` FOREIGN KEY (`following_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`))
CREATE TABLE `followers` (`user_id` integer,`follower_id` integer,PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`follower_id`),CONSTRAINT `fk_followers_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`),CONSTRAINT `fk_followers_followers` FOREIGN KEY (`follower_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`))
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually it's possible with a single join table as well:

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name       string
    Followings []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;joinForeignKey:user_Id;JoinReferences:following_id"`
    Followers  []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;joinForeignKey:following_id;JoinReferences:user_Id"`
}
```

Created tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` integer,`created_at` datetime,`updated_at` datetime,`deleted_at` datetime,`name` text,PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
CREATE TABLE `user_relations` (`user_id` integer,`following_id` integer,PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`following_id`),CONSTRAINT `fk_user_relations_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`),CONSTRAINT `fk_user_relations_followings` FOREIGN KEY (`following_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`))
```

And you can use it as follows:

```
db.AutoMigrate(&User{})

user1 := User{Name: "John"}
user2 := User{Name: "Tom", Followings: []*User{&user1}}
db.Save(&user2)

var users []User
db.Debug().Preload("Followings").Preload("Followers").Find(&users)

str, _ := yaml.Marshal(&users)
println(string(str))
```

Output:

```yaml
- model:
    id: 1
    createdat: 2020-09-08T22:47:33.910748505+02:00
    updatedat: 2020-09-08T22:47:33.910748505+02:00
    deletedat:
      time: 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
      valid: false
  name: Tom
  followings:
  - model:
      id: 2
      createdat: 2020-09-08T22:47:33.910906472+02:00
      updatedat: 2020-09-08T22:47:33.910906472+02:00
      deletedat:
        time: 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
        valid: false
    name: John
    followings: []
    followers: []
  followers: []
- model:
    id: 2
    createdat: 2020-09-08T22:47:33.910906472+02:00
    updatedat: 2020-09-08T22:47:33.910906472+02:00
    deletedat:
      time: 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
      valid: false
  name: John
  followings: []
  followers:
  - model:
      id: 1
      createdat: 2020-09-08T22:47:33.910748505+02:00
      updatedat: 2020-09-08T22:47:33.910748505+02:00
      deletedat:
        time: 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
        valid: false
    name: Tom
    followings: []
    followers: []
```

You could even preload more levels of followers-followings:

```golang
db.Debug().Preload("Followings").Preload("Followers").Preload("Followings.Followers").Preload("Followings.Followings").Find(&users)
```

Unfortunately preloading with [Joins](https://gorm.io/id_ID/docs/preload.html#Joins-Preloading) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The two tables don't share the common sense of the "following" relationship. If we say `userA` now follows `userB`, the reverse relationship must be also manually created that `userB` now has a follower `userA`. I'm trying to do it with just one many2many table.

Comment: @mehdy yes, you are right. It seems I misunderstood the requirements.