# Bidirectional many2many relationship in gorm doesnt work properly

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

#### Summary

Tried to implement [DUPLICATE: Bidirectional many2many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782715/how-to-create-a-bidirectional-many2many-relationship-in-gorm?rq=1) solution. After appending different users to the `"Followings"` and `"Followers"` fields, any user added to the `Following` field is also being added to `Followers` field, and vice versa.
The same happens with `BlockedBy` and `Blocking` fields.

I defined `User` `Following` and `Blocking`struct types as follows

```
type User struct {
    Email                 string          `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"email"`
    ...
    UserId                string          `gorm:"primary_key;not null" json:"userid"`
}
type Following struct {
    ID         string  `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    User       User    `gorm:"foreignKey:ID;references:UserId"`
    Followings []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;foreignKey:ID;joinForeignKey:UserA;references:UserId;joinReferences:UserB;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    Followers  []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;foreignKey:ID;joinForeignKey:UserB;references:UserId;joinReferences:UserA;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
}
type Blocking struct {
    ID        string  `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    User      User    `gorm:"foreignKey:ID"`
    BlockedBy []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_blocks;foreignKey:ID;joinForeignKey:UserIdBlocked;joinReferences:UserId;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    Blocking  []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_blocks;foreignKey:ID;joinForeignKey:UserId;joinReferences:userIdBlocked;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
}
```

#### Loading method

Here's how I first initialized and load some data for testing purposes:
// Load autogenerates the tables and records

```
func Load() {
    db, err := database.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Creates table for each model
    err = db.Debug().DropTableIfExists(
        &models.User{},
        &models.Following{},
        &models.Blocking{},
    ).Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //ERROR while using Postgres on Post model
    err = db.Debug().AutoMigrate(
        &models.User{},
        &models.Following{},
        &models.Blocking{},
    ).Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for i, _ := range users {
        err = db.Debug().Model(&models.User{}).Create(&users[i]).Error
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        userfollowings[i].ID = users[i].UserId
        blocked_users[i].ID = users[i].UserId
        err = db.Debug().Model(&models.Following{}).Create(&userfollowings[i]).Error
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        blocked_users[i].ID = users[i].UserId
        err = db.Debug().Model(&models.Blocking{}).Create(&blocked_users[i]).Error
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        err = db.Debug().Model(&userfollowings[i]).Related(&userfollowings[i].User, "user_id").Error
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = db.Debug().Model(&blocked_users[i]).Related(&blocked_users[i].User, "user_id").Error
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        if i == 0 {
            err = db.Model(&userfollowings[i]).Association("Followings").Append(&users[1], &users[2]).Error
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        } else if i == 1 {
            err = db.Model(&userfollowings[i]).Association("Followings").Append(&users[2]).Error
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        } else if i == 2 {
            err = db.Model(&userfollowings[i]).Association("Followings").Append(&users[3]).Error
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        } else if i == 3 {
            err = db.Model(&userfollowings[i]).Association("Followings").Append(&users[0]).Error
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fo_info := models.Following{}
            
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            console.Pretty(&fo_info)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Displaying Following model query result for UserId: 4

```
[2021-12-27 12:17:03]  [0.90ms]  SELECT * FROM `users` INNER JOIN `user_relation` ON `user_relation`.`user_user_id` = `users`.`user_id` WHERE (`user_relation`.`following_id` IN ('4'))  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 
{
"id": "4",
"User": {
"email": "q4@gmail.com",
"id": "4",
"displayName": "John Lennon",
},
"Followings": [
{
"email": "q@gmail.com",
...,
"userid": "1",
"displayName": "Ringo Starr",
},
],
"Followers": [
{
"email": "q@gmail.com",
...
"userid": "1",
"displayName": "Ringo Starr",
}
]
}
```

#### Expected result

```
[2021-12-27 12:17:03]  [0.90ms]  SELECT * FROM `users` INNER JOIN `user_relation` ON `user_relation`.`user_user_id` = `users`.`user_id` WHERE (`user_relation`.`following_id` IN ('4'))  
[0 rows affected or returned ] 
{
"id": "4",
"User": {
"email": "q4@gmail.com",
"id": "4",
"displayName": "John Lennon",
},
"Followings": [
{
"email": "q@gmail.com",
...,
"userid": "1",
"displayName": "Ringo Starr",
},
],
"Followers": [
{
"email": "q2@gmail.com",
...
"userid": "2",
"displayName": "George Harrison",
}
]
}
```

Since last Friday, I'm unable to make this working out. Tried different resource from Golang Gorm documentation and searched similar SOF Q&A, which didn't provide me any solution or guidance.